# Using move to insert into a STL container

Tags: c++11, stl

I am trying to better understand how move works when used in inserting an element into an STL container.  I am looking at a code where an objected is allocated using new (created on the heap).  Later on, when an insert is done, it seems the STL container allocates a new object and calls the move constructor.  Is there a way to make the STL container directly use the object (take over the object (ptr) that was alloced).

I have the following sample code for some additional questions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
        string   s1;

        foo() = default;

        foo(const foo& fm)
        { cout << "copy ctor" << endl; }

        foo(const foo&& fm)
        { cout << "move ctor" << endl; }

        foo& operator= (const foo& fm)
        { cout << "copy assign" << endl; return *this; }
};

vector<foo> vec_f;

int main()
{
    foo f1;
    vec_f.push_back(f1);
    cout << endl;

    foo f2;
    vec_f.push_back(move(f2));
    cout << endl;

    foo *f3 = new (foo);
    vec_f.push_back(*f3);
    cout << endl;

    foo *f4 = new (foo);
    vec_f.push_back(move(*f4));
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output as follow:

```
copy ctor

move ctor
copy ctor

copy ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor

move ctor
```

f1 : foo is created using copy ctor.  However, is this object created as a result of the STL code doing a new OR part of passing the object by value to a function (nothing to do with STL but a compiler thing)?  I am guessing the latter.  If so, where is the object creation when the element is inserted into the container?

f2 : foo is created using move ctor, by the STL code, right?  And why/how is the copy ctor invoked right after?  Is it because f2 is created on the stack (not heap)?  If so, how does the STL code figure that out?

f3 : Most puzzling to me.  Guessing the first copy ctor is invoked as part of passing a parameter by value (nothing to do with STL).  How/why are the other two copy ctor called.

f4 : STL invoking the move ctor, so the move ctor can use the guts of the foo object.  Is it possible to make the STL code just use the ptr (since it is created on heap).  My understanding is objects in STL container are created on the heap anyways.

Sorry about the long post.  Hopefully someone can shed some light.

Regards,
Ahmed.

Comment: Removed all the bits you told us to ignore. Please do that yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize is that `std::move` doesn't actually move an object. Where would it move it **to** ? It just allows moving **from**.

The second thing to realize is that `vector` manages its own memory. You can move many objects into a `vector`, but you can't give `vector` the memory alongside it (in which case you wouldn't even be moving the object at all)

Next up is `vector::push_back`. This can take either a `T const&` or a `T&&` depending on the argument. Only the latter case has the appropriate form for directly moving the value into `vector`. The first and third case fail because the expressions used cannot be moved from. The second case looks like it's not optimized (the copy ctor there probably would be optimized out in a release build).

Comment: The extra copies in #2 and #3 are due to reallocations and the move ctor of his class not being `noexcept`, so `push_back` must copy to preserve the strong exception safety guarantee. Debug/release has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The extra copy and move are made by `vector` itself, due to the re-allocations for `vector` size change.

You can print the memory address, like `cout << &vec_f[0] << endl;`, and its value changes after every `push_back()`

sample output:

```
copy ctor
0077C350
move ctor
move ctor
0077C588
move ctor
move ctor
copy ctor
0077C690
move ctor
move ctor
move ctor
move ctor
0077C8A8
```

If you add `vec_f.reserve(4);` after `vector<foo> vec_f;` then the output would be:

```
copy ctor
0087C308
move ctor
0087C308
copy ctor
0087C308
move ctor
0087C308
```

which should be your expectation.

P.S. I am using VS2013 Express.